# Getting the Bad request error 400 trying to send XMLHttpRequest to http://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation

Tags: javascript, cors, geolocation, xmlhttprequest, yandex

I need to send XMLHttpRequest to the Yandex server

I get the Bad Request error (400) and:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 400.

Here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation";

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  <some code>
};

var data = JSON.stringify({
 "common": {
   "version": "1.0",
   "api_key": <here goes API key>
   },
   "gsm_cells": [
   {
   "countrycode": params[0],
   "operatorid": params[1],
   "cellid": params[3],
   "lac": params[2],
   "age": 0
   }
   ]
});

xhr.send(data);
```

I can't find the solution for such a simple(?) thing!

Answer (score 1):

That API expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-formatted data that looks like this:

```
json={"common":{"version":"1.0","api_key":…}…}
```

That is, it needs a `key=value` pair, with the string `json` as the key and some JSON as the value.

But the code in the question is sending some JSON without the necessary `json=` preceding it. So the API endpoint responds with a 400 to tell you it’s a bad request.

So you can fix that and get a response back by making your code instead do this:

```
var data = 'json=' + JSON.stringify({…});
```

However, even after you do that, your browser’s still not going to let your frontend JavaScript access the response the server returns. Instead the browser will log an error message like this:

> Failed to load https://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin https://foo.bar is therefore not allowed access.

…because the CORS protocol requires browsers to disallow frontend JavaScript code access to responses from cross-origin requests unless the response has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

But you can get around that by making the request through a CORS proxy; complete example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
var url = "https://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation";

xhr.open("POST", proxyurl + url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(xhr.responseText)
};

var data = 'json=' + JSON.stringify({
  "common": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "api_key": "AAwkGkwBAAAA9muWLAMAKp9XjTBZtmOLeiBQJqHX6YEqNdUAAAAAAAAAAAAoEP1ZsBlcVFA_OpP55MK3Ek1r8A=="
  },
  "gsm_cells": [{
    "countrycode": 250,
    "operatorid": 99,
    "cellid": 42332,
    "lac": 36002,
    "age": 0
  }]
});
xhr.send(data);
```

Note however that if you send the request through a third-party proxy like that, the operator of the proxy can potentially snoop on your `api_key` and any other credentials you might send.

So you’re better off setting up your own proxy using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

---

As far as how the proxy in example above works: Prefixing https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ to your request URL causes the request to get made through that proxy, which then:

1. Forwards the request to whatever https://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation.
2. Receives the response from https://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation.
3. Adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response.
4. Passes that response, with that added header, back to your requesting frontend code.

The browser will then allow your frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

---

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thx for a quick and very well explained answer! You were right, adding "json = ... " to the data query fixes the first error.

Although I think there must be another solution but proxy to resolve second issue because yandex.geolocation is a public service and must work with requests from the different servers.

Comment: Yeah it works from any non-browser tool or backend programming runtime, but as far as making it work for requests made directly from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, I guarantee you there’s definitely not any other way to make it work other than using a CORS proxy in the way described in the answer. Browsers will otherwise block your code from getting to the response, because browsers by default block all access to responses from cross-origin requests, and the only way to make them not block like that is to get them an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response

Answer (score 1):

Suggested sulution will not work correctly in common case, but works correctly for gcm cell. It's because yandex.net/geolocation service used to getting location of user based on WiFi network, gcm cell or ip address.

When need use only IP based way then required configuration CORS on your web server.